# Pass an image to a canvas with dataurl

Tags: html, canvas, data-url

I am trying to make an image being passed to a canvas from a weburl.
The code has been taken from this [question][1] which is accepted but for some reason it does not work on me on firefox or chrome.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
Here you are:

```
var myCanvas = document.getElementById('my_canvas_id');
var ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image;
img.onload = function(){
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0); // Or at whatever offset you like
};

  img.src = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASwAAACWCAYAAABkW7XSAAAAxUlEQVR4nO3BMQEAAADCoPVPbQhfoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOA1v9QAATX68/0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=';
```

Comment: The code there is fine.Please share your version of the code, ideally with a live-code (inline or fiddle)

Comment: Can you paste the code you have used.  I know you mention you've taken the specific code, but you might have copied some things in the wrong order, or have a bug somewhere accidentally which we won't be able to see without the code

Comment: Please see the EDIT above. I didn't put a js fiddle cause this must be accompanied by code thing has troubled me a bit..

Comment: Your question is now completely different than it was before you got an answer... you should rollback to the original edit 1 and post a new question with the new code presented which has nothing to do with the original linked code, or the first edit.

Comment: Ok thank you very much. Why did you delete your answer i was ready to accept it..

Comment: @daab the answer wouldn't fit the new edit. Its now undeleted as the question is back to the original edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason nothing shows is that the provided Data-URI contains no data, that is, it is 300x150 fully transparent:

> data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASwAAACWCAYAAABkW7XSAAAAxUlEQVR4nO3BMQEAAADCoPVPbQhfoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOA1v9QAATX68/0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=

My guess is that you along the way saved an empty canvas as Data-URI using `toDataURL()` and is now using that for loading an image.

Try this URL instead and you will see it works (red image of 300x150):

> data:image/png;base64,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

```js
var myCanvas = document.getElementById('my_canvas_id');
var ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image;
img.onload = function(){
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0); // Or at whatever offset you like
};

img.src = "data:image/png;base64,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";
```

```html
<canvas id="my_canvas_id"></canvas>
```

```js
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle="red";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,300,150);
document.write(c.toDataURL());
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: @daad I already did before answering :) You can run the code and see it works now (the data-uri in your post contains a transparent image only).